# Posição da pagina no WebViewer Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Alguem sabe me dizer se tem como eu setar uma posição de uma pagina web na hora de iniciar o App que tem uma WebViewer, exemplo ao abrir a pagina ela mostra inicialmente do meio.

Answer (score 0):

Tente o seguinte código:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView); 
webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
```

Eu peguei no seguinte tópico: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21931728/how-to-center-content-in-webview-android

Comment: Não deu certo pois o setDefaultZoom() foi descontinuada.